# I want to retrieve the filename without extension from an url with php

Tags: php, regex, format

I have an url which contains various POST-DATA in it And an image file at last.
My link is : `http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=565dbca63791e5.87676354.png`

I want to seperate the `565dbca63791e5.87676354.png` from the url and seperate the extension (.png) from it.

I can do it :but it is from only plain URL:

```
$path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
$file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "index.php"
$file = basename($path, ".php"); // $file is set to "index"
```

Comment: Have you considered [`parse-url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)?

Comment: parse_url to extract the query string, followed by parse_str to decompse the query string into key:value pairs

Comment: If you assure that `signature=565dbca63791e5.87676354.png` will be present and always at the last, heres a verbose one liner `$signature = pathinfo(substr(strrchr($url, "="), 1), PATHINFO_FILENAME);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: use `parse_url()` as suggested in the comments. If you however opt for a regex solution, consider the following code:

```
$str = "http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=565dbca63791e5.87676354.png";
$regex = "/signature=(?<signature>[^&]+)/";
// that is: match signature= literally, then match everything up to a new ampersand and save it to the group "signature"
preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);
$signature = $matches["signature"];
$ext = substr(strrchr($signature, '.'), 1);

print "Signature: $signature with extension: $ext";
// prints out: Signature: 565dbca63791e5.87676354.png with extension: png
```

See a working PHP fiddle [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cdeaaf06a9bd32ec7d219e4443faeffdf1f8b299).

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = $_REQUEST['signature'];
$pathinfo = pathinfo($filename);
```

`$pathinfo['filename']` will print `565dbca63791e5.87676354` and `$pathinfo['extension']` will be `png`.

Comment: This only works if the string is an actual request not if you want to deal with it elsewhere. Nevertheless, +1 for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand you, then you need some function like this

```
$arr = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signature']);
function arrayFilter($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$item){
        if(!next($arr)){
            $result['extension'] = $item;
        } else {
            $result['value'] .= $item . '.'; 
        }
    }
    $result['value'] = substr($result['value'], 0, -1);
    return $result;
}
$data= arrayFilter($arr);
```

And will print 
     `[value] => 565dbca63791e5.87676354 [extension] => png`